# i want ot remove header of a website in flutter webview (new version)

Tags: javascript, flutter, webview

this is my code below,
i am loading a website in webview flutter app through   `webview_flutter:`
dependency,
this is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({super.key});

  @override
  State<Homepage> createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WebViewController webViewController = WebViewController();
    return WebViewWidget(
      controller: webViewController
        ..runJavaScript(
            "document.getElementByTagName('header-bottom')[0].style.display='none'")
        ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
        ..loadRequest(
          Uri.parse('https://auctionwind.com'),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

how can i remove header-bottom tag from this website.also i tried with "header" tag, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your script after your page has finished loading, your are using `webview_flutter`

so in that case, `onPageFinished` will be inside `setNavigationDelegate`

```
WebViewWidget(
  controller: webViewController 
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setNavigationDelegate(
         NavigationDelegate(  
           onPageFinished: (String url) {
               webViewController.runJavaScript(
                  "document.getElementsByClassName('header-bottom')[0].style.display='none'");
               }, 
       ),
      )
    ..loadRequest(
      Uri.parse('https://auctionwind.com'),
    ),
);
```

as your element has class name we can remove it by using getElementsByClassName

Comment: Tried this but not working,

 I/chromium(12144): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByTagName is not a function", source: https://auctionwind.com/ (1)

Comment: i tried changing URL, it is working but not working on this particular website, auctionwind.com

Comment: I have updated answer, its working properly now

Comment: i figured it now, thanks anyway!